# Link tag not working while linking a css file

Tags: html, css, tags

I'm using link tag to use a css file but it's not working. I used below tag
link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main/css" /> Any solutions?

Comment: Please provide example of both cases. As of now, your question is unclear and required editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML5 standards, using the `bgcolor` attribute is deprecated. So, if we're following the current standards, we don't use the `bgcolor` attribute.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20100304/body.html#body-constraints

The official W3C documentation says, "The bgcolor attribute on the body element is obsolete. Use CSS instead."

The `bgcolor` attribute was the standard way of adding background color to `body` before HTML5. However, as of now, one must use CSS, i.e. using either a `<link rel="stylesheet">` element, or a `<style>` tag, or even the `style` attribute.

Therefore, the alternative is to use `<body style="background-color: black;">` or to specify the following in your stylesheet (inline or external):

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}
```